# Check if Object contains value in arraylist doesn't work

Tags: java, arraylist

i have a arrayList private ArrayList Modules; where i want to store Module Objects, i then want to check if there is a object with the same moduleNummer as the inserted one, this works partially, when i only enter the same moduleNummer it works fine, when i enter a second(different) number it will add a new module with the number two, but when i want to add another week to the Module with number 2 it will not work, i dont uderstand why this is happening

```
public void addModule(int moduleNummer, int weekNummer, int weekUren) throws ParseException {
     if(Modules.size()==0) {
                    System.out.print("array size == 0");
                    Modules.add(new Module(moduleNummer));
                    Modules.get(0).addWeek(new ModuleWeek(weekNummer,weekUren));
                    return;
     }
     else{
        for (int i = 0; i < Modules.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print("entered loop \n");
            System.out.print("arraySize:"+ Modules.size() + "\n");
            System.out.print("selected array:"+Modules.get(i).getModuleNummer() + "\n");
            System.out.print("inserted:"+moduleNummer  + "\n");
            int inArrayModuleNummer = Modules.get(i).getModuleNummer();
            if (inArrayModuleNummer == moduleNummer ) {

                System.out.print("inserted Module number excists \n");
                Modules.get(i).addWeek(new ModuleWeek(weekNummer, weekUren));
                return;
            }
            else {
                System.out.print("inserted module number does not excist and the arraySize != 0");
                Module m = new Module(moduleNummer);
                m.addWeek(new ModuleWeek(weekNummer, weekUren));
                Modules.add(m);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail what this code is supposed to do and what attempts you've made to debug it on your own?

Comment: Perhaps use a `Map` instead of a `List`?  (Iterating through the list every time could get quite expensive.)

Comment: Your loop is not adding a new value when it doesn't exist. It adds a new value when the first value in the list is not the same.

Comment: You need to add second module to modules and then fetch second module from moduleslist and add week.  Hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your logic where you check in the loop is not correct.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Modules.size(); i++) {
        ...
        if (inArrayModuleNummer == moduleNummer ) {

            System.out.print("inserted Module number excists \n");
            Modules.get(i).addWeek(new ModuleWeek(weekNummer, weekUren));
            return;
        }
        else {
            System.out.print("inserted module number does not exist and the arraySize != 0");
            Module m = new Module(moduleNummer);
            m.addWeek(new ModuleWeek(weekNummer, weekUren));
            Modules.add(m);
            return;
        }
    }
```

Here, you consider that the module number doesn't exit in `Modules` as soon the first iteration if the first module of `Modules` doesn't match. You should conclude this only when you iterated over all elements.

The code in the `else` part should be moved after the iteration. The `return` is not required any longer.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < Modules.size(); i++) {
        ...
        if (inArrayModuleNummer == moduleNummer ) {

            System.out.print("inserted Module number excists \n");
            Modules.get(i).addWeek(new ModuleWeek(weekNummer, weekUren));
            return;
        }
    }
     // if you are here, the module number has no matching            
    System.out.print("inserted module number does not excist and the arraySize != 0");
    Module m = new Module(moduleNummer);
    m.addWeek(new ModuleWeek(weekNummer, weekUren));
    Modules.add(m);
```

Comment: i just refactored my code to this, and it seems to be working now, thanks!